# In XAML, how can i set a ENTRY.Text default for a Binding variable?

Tags: c#, xaml, triggers, maui

I have a SQLite database with some tables. One of them is a 'Result' table with columns ('unique_number', 'description', 'type', 'units', 'result_entry').

Now in XAML I bind a Results 'ObservableCollection' in a CollectionView:

```
<CollectionView ItemsSource="{Binding Results}" IsEnabled="{Binding IsBusy}">
  <CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
    <DataTemplate x:DataType="model:Result">
       <Frame>
```

Created a frame which displays all the info in a grid, with a conditional trigger on < Entry >:

```
<Label Grid.Column="0" Text="{Binding description}"/>
<Label Grid.Column="0" Text="{Binding type}"/>
<Entry Grid.Column="1" Text="{Binding result_entry}">
  <Entry.Triggers>
    <MultiTrigger TargetType="Entry">
      <MultiTrigger.Conditions>
        <BindingCondition Binding="{Binding type}" Value="time" />
        <BindingCondition Binding="{Binding result_entry}" Value="" />
      </MultiTrigger.Conditions>
      <Setter Property="Text" Value="{Binding Source={x:Static sys:DateTime.Now},StringFormat='{0:HH:mm}'}" />
    </MultiTrigger>
  </Entry.Triggers>
</Entry>
```

In the case, when a record is shown with 'type' "time" AND no time has been entered. Entry.Text is prefilled with the current time.

Now my problem is, i lose the Binding to the variable 'result_entry'. So when i save the record, the column 'result_entry' is not updated. Is there a way to prefill the Entry WITH the conditions AND maintain the Binding?

Edit: renamed entry to result_entry

Comment: No. If you overwrite `Text`, then you've lost the Binding. You'll need to use a different technique. If you have a binding, then you'll have to alter the bound variable, not the value of property text. Hopefully someone else will come along with a suggestion about how to accomplish your goal.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use the `DataTrigger` in the binding.

Here is the official document:https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/fundamentals/triggers#data-triggers

In addition, you need to change the DataTrigger's setter, such as:

```
<DataTrigger TargetType="Entry"
                 Binding="{Binding entry}"
                 Value="{x:Null}">
    <Setter Property="Text"
        Value="{Binding Source={x:Static sys:DateTime.Now},StringFormat='{0:HH:mm}'}" />
</DataTrigger>
```

These lines code means that if the value of the entry is null, set the Entry's text as the current time.

**Update**

Override the get method, such as:

```
public string Entry
    {
        
        get
        {
            if(entry != null)
              return entry;
            else
              return DateTime.Now.ToString();
        }
    }
```

Comment: First, let's change entry to result_entry, so it's more clear :p

Thanks for your comment. This is more or less the same way as i'm doing right now in BindingCondition. Datatrigger is also 'a' condition on which the setter will overwrite the Entry.Text. Nonetheless I lose the binding to result_entry (because you overwrite it with "Binding Source=........DateTime.Now......").

Comment: Sorry for my careless, but you can do this by overriding the get method of the entry variable. When the value is null, return current time.@DrahciReD

Comment: You can check the update answer.@DrahciReD

Comment: I tried it this way, even with a private string. It did work, but for some reason, when i clear the result_entry Entry field (and then save it), it will save result_entry with "datetime.now.tostring" anyway. Maybe it has to do something with the way "MySqlConnection" get's the object (to save it) and will 'get' the current time (because result_entry was null).

Answer (score 0):

I did manage to solve it, but this solution feels off :|

```
<Entry Grid.Column="1" Text="{Binding result_entry}" BackgroundColor="LightGrey">
  <Entry.Triggers>
    <DataTrigger TargetType="Entry" Binding="{Binding type}" Value="time">
      <Setter Property="IsVisible" Value="false"/>
       <Setter Property="Text" Value=""/>
    </DataTrigger>
  </Entry.Triggers>
</Entry>
<Entry Grid.Column="1" Text="" BackgroundColor="LightGrey" IsVisible="false">
  <Entry.Triggers>
    <DataTrigger TargetType="Entry" Binding="{Binding type}" Value="time">
      <Setter Property="IsVisible" Value="true"/>
      <Setter Property="Text" Value="{Binding result_entry, Converter={StaticResource NullToTime}}"/>
    </DataTrigger>
  </Entry.Triggers>
</Entry>
```

Basically I hide and unbind the first Entry when type = 'time' and show and bind the second Entry when type = time, with a 'NullToTime' converter.